# Creating stored procedure on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I'm trying to run the query below, that is stored in a `.sql` file, then read with [ioutils.ReadFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile) and executed on initialization

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS districts
(
    GeoCode integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name    varchar(32)
);

drop procedure if exists insert_district;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_district(in pgeocode int, in pname varchar(32))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO districts(geocode, name) VALUES (pgeocode, pname);
    SELECT * FROM districts where geocode = pgeocode;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using the database/sql package and run the query with [Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec)

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop procedure if exists insert_district;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert' at line 7
```

To the best of my knowledge my syntax is correct, and I tested it so I cannot figure out why the same exact query cannot be run properly from the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Go MySQL client does not support multiple SQL statements by default. You can't just feed it a text file with `;` separated statements.

See [Does a Go Mysql driver exist that supports multiple statements within a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548559/does-a-go-mysql-driver-exist-that-supports-multiple-statements-within-a-single-s) for details — there's an option you can use to allow multi-statements.

But that still won't support statements like `DELIMITER` which are not recognized by the MySQL Server. That's a [mysql client command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

You have two alternatives:

- Parse the .sql file to find statement terminators and run the statements one at a time.
- Execute the `mysql` client in a sub-process using the .sql file as input.

Comment: Thank you I decided to use multiple statments, although I had to remove the delimiter command.

Comment: Sure, you don't need `DELIMITER` unless you are running the whole file as a script with the `mysql` client. The purpose of `DELIMITER` is to solve the ambiguity of `;` being a statement terminator for statements inside the procedure body, but also a statement terminator for the whole CREATE PROCEDURE statement. If you execute one statement at a time with the API, there's no ambiguity.