# SQL Syntax error 1604 in CREATE PROCEDURE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am using this SQL query to generate a procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetSessionID //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSessionID(IN token VARCHAR(64), OUT id INTEGER)
BEGIN
    SELECT s.ID INTO id FROM Sessions AS s WHERE s.Token = token;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetSessionID //
CREATE PROCEDURE "GetSessi' at line 1
```

I tried using also `$$` as a delimiter, surrounding the procedure's name with double quotes and removing the space before the delimiters in the `DROP` statement and `END` statement. If I look at the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html), there is a space after the procedure name - I tried adding that too, and still doesn't work.

I am using Go's [`db.Exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) method to execute queries for creating tables and procedures, one after another.

I don't understand why do I get this error, as the syntax looks correct to me. Worked also in Goland's SQL runner, doesn't work in Go.

Comment: Since the error starts at the very beginning - there must be something wrong there. Do you try to execute 2 queries at the same time?

Comment: I tested the statements executing the `DELIMITER`, then the `DROP`, then the `CREATE`, and then the other `DELIMITER` statement in one go, using Goland's SQL runner. It works there, and the procedure exists on the database. Or do you mean something else by "at the same time"?

Comment: On the database you could just execute all that code at once. But using a framework try to  execute only the procedure. No delimiter definition, no drop. just the procedure: `CREATE PROCEDURE GetSessionID(IN token VARCHAR(64), OUT id INTEGER)
BEGIN
    SELECT s.ID INTO id FROM Sessions AS s WHERE s.Token = token;
END`

Comment: Tried it and it seems like there is a problem with the `DELIMITER` statement, as it gives me the same error on the next procedure I try to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem actually was: The MySQL Go driver for the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) library I am using, [`go-sql-driver`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) does not support multi statements by default. They can be activated as in [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#multistatements), although there are some limitations, documented there.

In conclusion, the problem is framework-related. I hope other people facing the same problem in Go will find this useful, as it isn't so obvious at the first glance. See also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548559/does-a-go-mysql-driver-exist-that-supports-multiple-statements-within-a-single-s)

EDIT: the `DELIMITER` statement isn't supported by the server itself, but by the MySQL command line. It won't work even as a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet.

`DROP PROCEDURE` statement needs to be ended by '`;`'. One small correction is needed with table `alias`.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetSessionID;

CREATE PROCEDURE GetSessionID(IN token VARCHAR(64), OUT id INTEGER)
BEGIN
  SELECT s.ID INTO id FROM Sessions s WHERE s.Token = token;
END //
    
DELIMITER ;
```